# "<method> takes no arguments (1 given)" but I gave none

Tags: python, methods, call

I am new to Python and I have written this simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

class Hello:
    def printHello():
        print('Hello!')

def main():
    helloObject = Hello()
    helloObject.printHello()   # Here is the error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run it (`./hello.py`) I get the following error message:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./hello.py", line 13, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "./hello.py", line 10, in main
>     helloObject.printHello()
> TypeError: printHello() takes no arguments (1 given)
> ```

Why does Python think I gave `printHello()` an argument while I clearly did not? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The error is referring to the implicit `self` argument that is passed implicitly when calling a method like `helloObject.printHello()`. This parameter needs to be included explicitly in the definition of an instance method. It should look like this:

```
class Hello:
  def printHello(self):
      print('Hello!')
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want `printHello` as instance method, it should receive self as argument always(ant python will pass implicitly) Unless you want `printHello` as a static method, then you'll have to use `@staticmethod`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

class Hello:
    def printHello(self):
        print('Hello!')

def main():
    helloObject = Hello()
    helloObject.printHello()   # Here is the error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As '@staticmethod'

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

class Hello:
    @staticmethod
    def printHello():
        print('Hello!')

def main():
    Hello.printHello()   # Here is the error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: [Class method](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) != static method.

Answer (score 6):

Calling a method on the instance of an object returns the object itself (usually `self`) to the object. For example, calling `Hello().printHello()` is the same as calling `Hello.printHello(Hello())`, which uses an instance of a `Hello` object as the first argument.

Instead, define your `printHello` statement as `def printHello(self):`