# Python - Gtk - paste from clipboard

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, glade

While building a simple GUI video downloader in python and with Glade3 I am stuck with pasting into a text entry box using an icon.

The application, and paste icon.

[image]

The python code:

```
# !/usr/python

import sys
import os
import subprocess as sp
try:
    from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
except:
    print('Gtk not available')
    sys.exit(1)
try:
    import pyGtk
    pyGtk.require('2.0')
except:
    pass



class VideoDownloader:

  def on_mainwindow_destroy(self, object, data=None):
    print "quit with cancel"
    Gtk.main_quit()

  def __init__(self):
    self.gladefile = "lib/videodownloder.glade" 
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder() 
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile) 
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)
    self.go = self.builder.get_object
    self.window = self.go("mainwindow")    
    self.window.show() 
    self.okbtn = self.go("okbutton")
    self.cancelbtn = self.go("cancelbutton")
    #self.restartswitch = self.go("restartswitch")
    self.contswitch = self.go("contswitch")
    self.vlcswitch = self.go("vlcswitch")
    self.urlentry = self.go("urlentry")
    self.filechooser = self.go("filechooser")
    self.clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)

  def on_urlentry_activate(self, widget):
    url = self.urlentry.get_text()
    print("the url is:" + url)

  def on_urlentry_icon_press(self):
    text = self.clipboard.set_text(self.urlentry.get_text(), -1)
    print("the urlentry paste icon was clicked | 'text' ")

  def on_urlentry_icon_press(self):
    text = self.clipboard.wait_for_text()
    print("the urlentry paste icon was clicked | 'text' ")
    if text != None:
      self.urlentry.set_text(text)
      print(" 'text' has been pasted to the urlentry")
    else:
      print("No text on the clipboard")

  def on_filechooser_file_activated(self, widget):
    myfile = self.filechooser.get_uri()
    print("the file is: " + myfile)

  def on_vlcswitch_activate(self, widget):
    print("VLC Switch has been activated")

  def on_contswitch_activate(self, widget):
    print("Continue switch has been acivated")

  def on_quitbutton_clicked(self, button):
    print("quit with the close button")
    Gtk.main_quit()


  def on_okbutton_clicked(self, button):
    myfile = self.filechooser.get_uri()
    url = self.urlentry.get_text()
    wgetcmd = ("wget -O 'myfile ' 'url' ")
    print("ok button has been clicked")
    print("wget will now be run with your args: " +myfile+url)
    os.system(wgetcmd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print("videodownloader is running")
  notify = os.system("notify-send --expire-time=5000 --icon='img/vid-down-logo.png' --app-name=VideoDownloader 'VideoDownloader' 'The VideoDownloader app is now running and ready!'")
  notify
  main = VideoDownloader()
  Gtk.main()
  print("videodownloader has stopped running")
```

When I run the code it mostly works but when I click the paste icon I get an error:

```
TypeError: on_urlentry_icon_press() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

I am fairly new to python and glade so I am probably making an elementary mistake but I do not know what is wrong and what the error means. I have searched but found only advice that didn't help.
[Such as this..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614123/method-takes-no-arguments-1-given-but-i-gave-none)
Any suggestions on how to fix this please?

Comment: Please edit question title - it has nothing to do with pasting from clipboard.

Comment: When faced with an error like this, define the function (in this case `on_urlentry_icon_press` as `on_urlentry_icon_press(self, *args)` and then inspect args to see what you get there. You can even leave the definition at that if you don't need anything from args.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `on_urlentry_icon_press` method only takes the `self` argument but it should take more than one because it is connected to the `icon-press` signal.

In the [documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Entry.html#Gtk.Entry.signals.icon_press) you can see that it takes:

- entry (a reference to the Gtk.Entry)
- position (whether it is the primary or secondary icon)
- event (e.g. whether it was a double click)

So it should look like this:

```
def on_urlentry_icon_press(self, entry, position, event):
    print('urlentry icon clicked')
```

Comment: Thanks @elya5, great info.