# robotframework is adding arguments where there are none: Type Error: takes no arguments (1 given)

Tags: robotframework

Robot is telling me that I'm providing too many arguments to my keyword. I've boiled it down to a base case where I have a keyword that should do nothing:

```
def do_nothing():
    """
    Does absolutly nothing
    """
```

Calling this keywork like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
testCaseOne
    do_nothing
```

Give this result:

```
TypeError: do_nothing() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Adding a parameter to the keyword definition fixes the problem. Why does robot seem to pass 1 parameter to each keyword, even if there are no parameters in the test case?

Comment: Is this keyword part of a class definition?

Comment: Yes it is, actually.  Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4445419/4099566).

The issue has nothing to do with the robotframework, and has every thing to do with Python; **Python implicitly passes the current instance of the class to method calls**, but I needed to explicitly declare the parameter. This is customarily named self:

```
def do_nothing(self):
```

This test runs.